# おまえのろいなー亀になっちゃうぞ DB Chapter 2

Tags: translation

This is Goku talking to Bulma who's taking too long to get ready.
Translated as: "If you were any slower, you'd turn into a turtle".

おまえ = you

のろ = slow

いなー = いない = ??

亀 = turtle

になっちゃう = turned into (completed action)

ぞ = emphasis

Is いない for "iru negated" or 以内 = less than?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This のろいなー is an i-adjective のろい ("slow") followed by a sentence-end particle な (a masculine variant of ね). な is elongated to add emotion. There is no negation.